# How do I correctly pass DateTime from C# to SQL?

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I'm attempting to run a stored procedure from C# and am getting a conversion error while unit testing. Every search result for this issue I've seen indicated that using ToString() is not the preferred way to pass DateTime's.

C# Code:

```
using (SqlConnection lvConn = new SqlConnection(gvSQLConnectionS))
{
    lvConn.Open();
    SqlCommand lvCmd = new SqlCommand(gvSQLsp, lvConn);
    lvCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    lvCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(gvSQLparamFunction, gvSQLfunctionUpdLE));
    lvCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(gvSQLparamID, lvAAAID));
    lvCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(gvSQLparamName, lvName));
    lvCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter(gvSQLparamPath, lvPath)); 
    SqlParameter lvParameterLE = lvCmd.Parameters.Add(gvSQLparamLE, SqlDbType.DateTime);
    SqlDateTime lvDTnow = new SqlDateTime(DateTime.Now);
    lvParameterLE.Value = lvDTnow;
    lvCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

SQL Setup:
Last Executed (datetime, null)

Stored Procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_BackupCleaner]
    @lvFunction int,
    @lvAAAID varchar(12) = NULL,
    @lvAAAID_new varchar(12) = NULL,
    @lvName varchar(35) = NULL,
    @lvName_new varchar(35) = NULL,
    @lvPath varchar(255) = NULL,
    @lvPath_new varchar(255) = NULL,
    @lvLastExecuted datetime = NULL
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @lvSQL varchar(max)
```

---

```
IF @lvFunction = 6
    BEGIN
        SET @lvSQL = 'UPDATE [dbo].[Backup_Paths]
                SET [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Last Executed] = '+@lvLastExecuted+'
                WHERE [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[AAA Client ID] = '''+@lvAAAID+'''
                AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Process Name] = '''+@lvName+'''
                AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[UNC Path] = '''+@lvPath+''''
    END

execute(@lvSQL)
END
```

Exception thrown:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Comment: What does your stored procedure take for params? Remove the quotes from `@lvLastExecuted`.

Comment: Why are you using string concatenation within your stored procedure? That looks just as bad as doing it within C#.

Comment: Can you include how you execute the dynamic sql string `@lvSQL`

Comment: What is the type and value of `gvSQLparamLE`

Comment: did you try to add the Direction = ParameterDirection.Input to the sql parameter of the DateTime?

Comment: I've updated my question to include the parameters definitions.
I'm guessing I'm doing something stupid with the SQL stored procedure itself.

Comment: Just pass it as any other time of *parameter*. Use the *correct* type and *DON'T* use string concatenation. There's absolutely no reason to construct that `@lvSQL` statement by concatenation. Juste write and execute the `UPDATE` statement

Comment: @Azreal you are building strings instead of just executing the statements. What's the point of `@lvSQL`? Just write `UPDATE.. SET [Last Executed] = @lvLastExecuted ....`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `SET [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Last Executed] = '+@lvLastExecuted+'` that is just as bad as using `.ToString()` in C#.

If you are not further dynamically modifying `@lvSQL` you can directly execute the query

```
IF @lvFunction = 6
BEGIN
    UPDATE [dbo].[Backup_Paths]
            SET [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Last Executed] = @lvLastExecuted
            WHERE [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[AAA Client ID] = @lvAAAID 
            AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Process Name] =  @lvName
            AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[UNC Path] = @lvPath
END
```

If you are going to further edit the query you need to use [`sp_executesql`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-executesql-transact-sql) and forward the parameters on to the dynamic query.

```
IF @lvFunction = 6
BEGIN
    SET @lvSQL = 'UPDATE [dbo].[Backup_Paths]
            SET [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Last Executed] = @lvLastExecuted
            WHERE [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[AAA Client ID] = @lvAAAID
            AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Process Name] = @lvName
            AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[UNC Path] = @lvPath'
END

SET @lvSQL = @lvSQL + ' WHERE [dbo].[Backup_Paths].SomeProp = 7'

execute sp_executesql @lvSQL, '@lvFunction int,
                               @lvECMID varchar(12),
                               @lvECMID_new varchar(12),
                               @lvName varchar(35),
                               @lvName_new varchar(35),
                               @lvPath varchar(255),
                               @lvPath_new varchar(255),
                               @lvLastExecuted datetime',
                      @lvFunction,
                      @lvECMID,
                      @lvECMID_new,
                      @lvName,
                      @lvName_new,
                      @lvPath,
                      @lvPath_new,
                      @lvLastExecuted;
```

Comment: Yeah, '@lvSQL' wasn't changing throughout the sp. I am running different SQL commands based on '@lvFunction', so removing '@lvSQL' entirely is the route I'll take. So far changing the '@lvFunction' = 6 portion has corrected the conversion issue. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use dynamic SQL. In general dynamic SQL should be avoided. It's very rare to find a case where dynamic SQL can't be replaced by something better.

Just write and run the statement you want :

```
IF @lvFunction = 6
    BEGIN
        UPDATE [dbo].[Backup_Paths]
            SET [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Last Executed] = @lvLastExecuted
            WHERE [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[AAA Client ID] = @lvAAAID
            AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[Process Name] = @lvName
            AND [dbo].[Backup_Paths].[UNC Path] = @lvPath
    END
```

**NOTE**

If the stored procedure performs a lot of different tasks it's a strong sign that it should be broken into separate procedures.

Answer (score -1):

[image]The problem is trying to concat the Datetime variable with the string literal using the `+` operator. If you are using SqlServer 2012 or higher, you can use `CONCAT` and this will fix the problem. (but probably make your query fail when that value is NULL)

```
CONCAT('select blah blah blah', @myDateTimeValue);
```

Comment: This won't make any difference. This will *still* try to convert `datetime` into a string and concatenate it. It's no different than `'select blah blah blah' + @myDateTimeValue`

Comment: You can try it yourself, it will make a difference, no error is thrown.

Comment: Why don't *you* try it and post the results? The OP's query uses parameters in the middle of the string, not the end. Check the *documentation* too `All arguments are implicitly converted to string types and then concatenated.`

Comment: You mean the failing example. This **FAILS** with the exact same error message as the OP's question

Comment: Exactly, but the first test does not, which is my point, my suggestion will fix the OP's problem

Comment: Try **executing** the string, not printing it.

Comment: It fails then because they need to use a convert in their query. And it will still fail if the datetime is null. But I answered why they are getting the exception and how to fix it. Idk what OP wants to do with the query. They didn't have that in the example. I said his query will still fail if he tries to execute, but that is for different reasons then he is asking about. I am explaining how to fix OP's current problem, and both of these issues would be fixed if they used parameterized queries, instead of just plain dynamic.

Comment: No you haven't. At best you introduced a different bug. You didn't even try a *query* though. If you had, eg used `CONCAT('SELECT * FROM MyTABLE Where MyDate=',@someDate)` you'd get `SELECT * FROM MyTABLE Where MyDate=Jul 19 2017  6:18PM` or whatever the date format for your locale is. It's still dynamic sql, it still has conversion problems, it can still fail even if you use quotes. It's still vulnerable to SQL injection

Comment: And your answer doesn't even mention parameterized queries. It only shows string concatenation using a different operator

Comment: That was my deleted answer, and I didn't try a query because you don't know that he is trying a query.